# Does the version of Visual Studio Code matter while importing packages in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, github, visual-studio-code

I have had a problem over and over again where my imports say that there is no URI. I am currently trying to import a package from Github. My import should be correct, my pubspec.yaml should be correct:

```
    flutter_import_name:
      git:
        url: //https:stuff
```

```
import 'package:name/name.dart';
```

It just keeps saying that there is no URI. I'm now wondering if there might be something with the version of VS Code. If there are any other mistakes I might be making or other suggestions to import better that would be appreciated.

Comment: Check the indentation in your yaml. Does you `flutter pub get` work from the command line. Is pubspec.lock updated correctly?

Comment: @RichardHeap Indentation is good, flutter pub get works, but not sure is pubspec.lock updated correctly. Not sure how to check that.

Comment: Just look inside... do you see a direct main dependency with the correct name, url and version?

Comment: @RichardHeap I don't see its name, I don't think it is in the pubspec.lock

Comment: Check your indentation again - as it's wrong in the question. The 'g' of git should be under the 'u' of flutter. https://dart.dev/tools/pub/dependencies#git-packages

Comment: @RichardHeap I just checked, it was just an error in the question, in the code 'g' is under the 'u'. I'm starting to think that it might be a server url problem. I have tried using 'flutter clean' then 'flutter pub get' and updating VS Code but it still can't find a URI.